# Laravel on wamp

Tags: laravel, wamp, vhosts

I've set up wamp and laravel with composer, and virtualhosts too. Whenever I go to my project folder 'localhost/project/', or my vhost 'project.dev', I only see the file directory of the laravel project. Yet if I go to 'project.dev/public' or 'project.dev/server.php' it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your DocumentRoot (in your vhosts file) to `C:\location\of\laravel\public` instead of `C:\location\of\laravel\`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, dont forget to also tell Apache from where it is allowed to accespt connections as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```